# how to run function in coffeescript for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, coffeescript

I write coffeescript like this:

```
split_typer_text = typer_text.split ''
test = (char) ->
  setTimeout (-> element.text(element.text() + char)), 100
test char for char in split_typer_text
```

but coffeescript complier it to this:

```
test = function(char) {
    return setTimeout((function() {
      return element.text(element.text() + char);
    }), 100);
  };
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = split_typer_text.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    char = split_typer_text[_i];
    _results.push(test(char));
  }
  return _results;
```

I want run function,not need a array.
How to do?

Answer (score 0):

When I compile that source, I get this...

```
var char, split_typer_text, test, _i, _len;

split_typer_text = typer_text.split('');

test = function(char) {
  return setTimeout((function() {
    return element.text(element.text() + char);
  }), 100);
};

for (_i = 0, _len = split_typer_text.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  char = split_typer_text[_i];
  test(char);
}
```

Perhaps update your coffeescript...

```
bash-3.2$ coffee --version
CoffeeScript version 1.6.2
```

Comment: my code is:
    ->
      split_typer_text = typer_text.split ''
      test = (char) ->
        setTimeout (-> element.text(element.text() + char)), 100
      test char for char in split_typer_text

Comment: yes - as it is in your question. When I compile that with coffeescript, I get the out put I put in my answer. You are getting something different - and I suspect because your coffeescript is an old or modified version. update your coffeescript, and you will get results like mine.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the test function, right here:

```
_results.push(test(char));
#-------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

Everything is an expression in CoffeeScript and that includes a `for` loop. The result of a `for` loop is an array, hence the `_results` array and the `_results.push` in the compiled JavaScript.

In some cases, the CoffeeScript compiler can guarantee that the `for` loop's value won't be used so the `_results` stuff can be optimized out when compiling. For example, in this CoffeeScript:

```
f = ->
    i for i in [0..11]
    42
```

the `for` loops value is guaranteed to never be used so there is no array in the JavaScript:

```
var f;

f = function() {
  var i, _i;

  for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 11; i = ++_i) {
    i;
  }
  return 42;
};
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3af%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20i%20for%20i%20in%20%5B0..11%5D%0A%20%20%20%2042%0A).

However, in this case, the `for` loop is the function's return value so the array is needed:

```
f = ->
    i for i in [0..11]
```

and you'll see the array being populated in the JavaScript:

```
var f;

f = function() {
  var i, _i, _results;

  _results = [];
  for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 11; i = ++_i) {
    _results.push(i);
  }
  return _results;
};
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3af%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20i%20for%20i%20in%20%5B0..11%5D%0A).

If you're sure that you don't want to waste time with the array then you have to tell CoffeeScript that the array will not be used, how you do that depends on the context. For example, you could add an empty `return` to indicate that the surrounding function doesn't return anything:

```
f = ->
    i for i in [0..11]
    return
```

and you'll get this:

```
var f;

f = function() {
  var i, _i;

  for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 11; i = ++_i) {
    i;
  }
};
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3af%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20i%20for%20i%20in%20%5B0..11%5D%0A%20%20%20%20return).